# How Do You Properly Type Out This Countdown Timer Code?

Tags: javascript

I have this countdown timer code but if I just enter it as is I only get the text.

I tried putting <.script.> <./script.> at the beginning and end of it (without the ".") but it still does not show the timer.

How do am I supposed to have this code typed so that it doesn't just show as a block of text and shows as the timer?

The code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   var totalTime = 30; // Amout of time (sec)
   var halfTime = Math.floor(totalTime / 2);

   if (!Cookies.get('cdTime')) {
      var now = $.now(); // First time on page
      Cookies.set('firstTime', now, {
         expires: 7,
         path: '/'
      });
      Cookies.set('cdTime', totalTime, {
         expires: 7,
         path: '/'
      });
      var runTimer = Cookies.get('cdTime');
   } else {
      var currentTime = $.now();
      var usedTime = (currentTime - Cookies.get('firstTime')) / 1000; // Calculate and convert into seconds
      var runTimer = Cookies.get('cdTime') - usedTime;
   }
   $('#cd').countdown({
      until: runTimer,
      compact: true,
      onExpiry: EndCountdown,
      onTick: Callbacks,
      layout: '{sn} seconds left...'
   });

   function Callbacks(periods) {
      if ($.countdown.periodsToSeconds(periods) === halfTime) {
         $('#cd').addClass('halfway');
      }
      else if ($.countdown.periodsToSeconds(periods) <= 0) {
         EndCountdown();
      }
   }

   function EndCountdown() {
      $('#cd').removeClass('halfway').addClass('ended');
      $('#cd').html('&#9829;');
   }

});
```

Comment: A quick look without running the code suggests that you need to be using jQuery. Are you using jQuery?

Comment: Wrapping the code in `<script>` tags will allow the code to run, but there's more you need to do. There are at least two external dependencies (jQuery, Cookies) that you need to load, and you may also need to create an element to hold the counter. I suggest you go back to the place you got this and read the documentation thoroughly.

Comment: Oh, that's what they meant by jQuery Countdown and JavaScript Cookie is needed to work.
I see. Thanks guys... I have no idea what those are so I guess I'll have to find another way to do this.